# Outlook constantly synchronizing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2013

One of my clients is currently experiencing the following problem:

As soon as he starts Outlook 2013, it tries to sync. However, he remains hanging.
With Outlook Start, the progress bar "Transmission" remains still, in the detail view it is stuck with the subscribed folders synchronization.

I just aborted the task and the transmission finished. But everytime he clicks on a folder like "Sent Mails" the sync starts again and is stuck. Inbetween the time Outlook is synchronizing (which is in this case forever) no mails can be received.

I already "repaired" the PST. Also Windows Updates didn't help. 3rd party Antivirus Software is temporarely disabled, but didn't help. Also the windows integrated Firewall allows communication inbound and outbound aswell.

Did anyone experience the same problem? Or does anyone have an idea? The customer can't receive mails atm, because this problem occurs permanently.

Comment: Used Office Version: Outlook 2013
OS: Windows 7, Build 7601

Comment: Did you try launching Outlook in safemode and then trying? Did you run an office repair? After both of this fails I would create a new profile in Outlook but this mostly looks like a add in issue.

Comment: @CAO No, thanks for the tipps, I gonna try them Thursday, when the customer is back in town.